# Network discovery Hyperledger fabric

Tags: java, sdk, hyperledger-fabric, service-discovery

I want to do a network discovery from sdk java , in order to get the list of existant peers and orderers from the network ... i saw this command  that gives a list of peers :

```
discover --peerTLSCA tls/ca.crt --userKey msp/keystore/fa65ea6028ce47de4163fb37b5f21529f657d978cd669337248dbfe00a7f74ee_sk --userCert msp/signcerts/Admin@org1.example.com-cert.pem --MSP Org1MSP --tlsCert tls/client.crt --tlsKey tls/client.key peers --server peer0.org1.example.com:7051
```

how can i replace that in java and also get the orderers list ... 
thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you use [fabric-gateway-java](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-gateway-java/), discovery is used under the hood, depending on your [connection options](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/developapps/connectionoptions.html).